# Convert List[(Int,String)] into List[Int] in scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

My goal is to to map every word in a text (Index, line) to a list containing the indices of every line the word occurs in. I managed to write a function that returns a list of all words assigned to a index.

The following function should do the rest (map a list of indices to every word):

```
def mapIndicesToWords(l:List[(Int,String)]):Map[String,List[Int]] = ???
```

If I do this:

```
l.groupBy(x => x._2)
```

it returns a `Map[String, List[(Int,String)]`. Now I just want to change the value to type `List[Int]`. 
I thought of using `.mapValues(...)` and fold the list somehow, but I'm new to scala and don't know the correct approach for this.

So how do I convert the list?

Comment: converting `List[(Int,String)] into List[Int]` is just doing a `.map(_._1)`

Comment: @RameshMaharjan thanks a lot

Comment: did you get it solved?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cleaner tuple groupBy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10783772/cleaner-tuple-groupby)

Comment: @RameshMaharjan yeah `l.groupBy(x => x._2).mapValues[List[Int]](f => f.map(_._1))` works great

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use foldLeft, you need just specify accumulator (in your case Map[String, List[Int]]), which will be returned as a result, and write some logic inside. Here is my implementation.

```
def mapIndicesToWords(l:List[(Int,String)]): Map[String,List[Int]] =
  l.foldLeft(Map[String, List[Int]]())((map, entry) =>
    map.get(entry._2) match {
      case Some(list) => map + (entry._2 -> (entry._1 :: list))
      case None => map + (entry._2 -> List(entry._1))
    }
  )
```

But with foldLeft, elements of list will be in reversed order, so you can use foldRight. Just change foldLeft to foldRight and swap input parameters, `(map, entry)` to `(entry, map)`.

And be careful, foldRight works 2 times slower. It is implemented using method reverse list and foldLeft.

Comment: According to the [source code](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.6/src/library/scala/collection/TraversableOnce.scala#L1), `foldRight` is implemented via `foldLeft` and neither one of them are recursive (tail or otherwise).

Comment: I know that all methods are implemented in imperative style, but I didn't know that foldRight is implemented as reverse.foldLeft. So, thank you for clarifying!

Answer (score 0):

```
scala> val myMap: Map[String,List[(Int, String)]]  = Map("a" -> List((1,"line1"), (2, "line")))
myMap: Map[String,List[(Int, String)]] = Map(a -> List((1,line1), (2,line)))

scala> myMap.mapValues(lst => lst.map(pair => pair._1))
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,List[Int]] = Map(a -> List(1, 2))
```